# How to prevent hive session timeout in RShiny application

Tags: r, hadoop, shiny, hive

I have a RShiny application which connects to a a datalake using RJDBC drivers using the following code snippet:

```
hadoop.class.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/hadoop"),pattern="jar", full.names=T);
hive.class.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib"),pattern="jar", full.names=T);
hadoop.lib.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib"),pattern="jar",full.names=T);
mapred.class.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/lib"),pattern="jar",full.names=T);
cp = c(hive.class.path,hadoop.lib.path,mapred.class.path,hadoop.class.path)
.jinit(classpath=cp,parameters="-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false")
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver","hive-jdbc.jar",identifier.quote="`")

conn <- dbConnect(drv, <Path to Hive server>, <SchemaName>)
```

As the application involves a lot of user intervention, a lot of time the application is idle but what we are experiencing is also that the hive session times out during these 'idle times' frequently and hence the users loses their progress. Is there anyway to keep this session active during multiple back and forth calls and during idle time of the application.

Following is the error that I get :

```
Warning: Error in .verify.JDBC.result: Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
JDBC ERROR: Invalid SessionHandle: SessionHandle <SessionId>
```

Comment: did you find any way to solve this?